# Dynamically create a gridview from a class(.cs) file

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, dynamic, .class-file

I want to create a gridview form a class and send that gridview as mail. I know the mailing part but how to create a gridview from a class file without using an aspx file.

I am doing so because a method will be called at a scheduled time using quartz.net and that method will create a gridview and send it as mail. Any suggestion how it can be done?

**EDIT:**
This gridview contains daily works for staffs (ie) each staff has 'n' number of works. So i have dynamically generate a gridview inside a foreach loop. How it can be done?

```
using Quartz;
public class SendMailJob : IJob
{
    public void Execute(JobExecutionContext context)
    {
        SendMail();
    }
    private void SendMail()
    {
        // put your send mail logic here
    }
}
```

and global.asax,

```
using Quartz;
using Quartz.Impl;

public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ISchedulerFactory schedFact = new StdSchedulerFactory();
        // get a scheduler
        IScheduler sched = schedFact.GetScheduler();
        sched.Start();
        // construct job info
        JobDetail jobDetail = new JobDetail("mySendMailJob", typeof(SendMailJob));
        // fire every day at 06:00
        Trigger trigger = TriggerUtils.MakeDailyTrigger(06, 00);
        trigger.Name = "mySendMailTrigger";
        // schedule the job for execution
        sched.ScheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: what about creating a html table using StringBuilder?

Comment: @sandy i have a datatable that ll be assigned to gridview datasource.

Comment: @Pandiay Chendur - can you explain, how triggering is done in quartz.net? are you calling any webpage or triggering an assembly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend creating an html table using StringBuilder rather than creating GridView.

Here is a similar post [Convert DataTable to HTML Table](http://forums.asp.net/t/1093574.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Am a bit unsure if i have understood your requirement correctly but you can create  a gridview dynamically from code using

```
Gridview myGrid = new GridView()
```

as long as you have referenced the System.Web.UI namespace from that class.

Also, the GridView has a method

```
    public virtual void RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)
```

which you can use to get a HTMLTextWriter with the Grids HTML which you can then pass on to your emailing class

Answer (score 0):

From you edit - I assume you want to create html content or gridview in SendMail() method, right?

if so, you can opt the following method

- Create an aspx page
- put your gridview in it and bind it with datatable
- Create httpWebrequest object and call newly created aspx page
- read the content using HttpWebResponse
- use this content to send mail.

here are some articles which will help you with httpwebrequest and httpwebresponse

[Working with HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse in ASP.NET](http://www.worldofasp.net/tut/WebRequest/Working_with_HttpWebRequest_and_HttpWebResponse_in_ASPNET_114.aspx)
[HttpWebResponse Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.aspx)
[HttpWebRequest Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx)